# Restart windowing for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, windowing

I have a list of strings, and I want to window them 'n' at a time. The window should re-start every time it encounters a certain string. This is the code I used:

```
i = 0
a = ['Abel', 'Bea', 'Clare', 'Abel', 'Ben', 'Constance', 'Dave', 'Emmet', 'Abel', 'Bice', 'Carol', 'Dennis']
n=3  
while i in range(len(a)-n+1):
  print('Window :', a[i:i+n])
  i += 1
  if a[i] == 'Abel':
      print()
      continue
```

and the output I get is:

```
Window : ['Abel', 'Bea', 'Clare']
Window : ['Bea', 'Clare', 'Abel']
Window : ['Clare', 'Abel', 'Ben']

Window : ['Abel', 'Ben', 'Constance']
Window : ['Ben', 'Constance', 'Dave']
Window : ['Constance', 'Dave', 'Emmet']
Window : ['Dave', 'Emmet', 'Abel']
Window : ['Emmet', 'Abel', 'Bice']

Window : ['Abel', 'Bice', 'Carol']
Window : ['Bice', 'Carol', 'Dennis']
```

while I would like it to re-start windowing every time 'Abel' comes into a position that isn't first, like:

```
#Expected result
Window : ['Abel' , 'Bea', 'Clare']

Window : ['Abel', 'Ben', 'Constance']
Window : ['Ben', 'Constance', 'Dave']
Window : ['Constance', 'Dave', 'Emmet']

Window : ['Abel', 'Bice', 'Carol']
Window : ['Bice', 'Carol', 'Dennis']
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "windowing" but do you simply want to skip printing when "Abel" is in the list but not the first item?

Comment: Yes @SitiSchu I would like to 'group' the strings n at a time until 'Abel', when the grouping should re-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

```py
data = [
    "Abel",
    "Bea",
    "Clare",
    "Abel",
    "Ben",
    "Constance",
    "Dave",
    "Emmet",
    "Abel",
    "Bice",
    "Carol",
    "Dennis",
]

data_size = len(data)
window_size = 3
restart_match_value = "Abel"

i = 0
j = 0

while i < data_size - window_size + 1:
    window = []
    should_restart = False
    for j in range(i, i + window_size):
        window.append(data[j])
        if len(window) > 1 and data[j] == restart_match_value:
            should_restart = True
            i = j - 1
    if should_restart:
        print()
    else:
        print("Window:", window)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't check if `a[i]` is `'Abel'`, you should check if the *next element after the window* is Abel, i.e. `a[i+n]`.

Also you should increase `i` after you check for your condition.

Last, when you do encounter `'Abel'`, you should increase your iterator `i` by 3, to skip the window by 3 positions as you expect.

I hope this helps:

```
i = 0
a = ['Abel', 'Bea', 'Clare', 'Abel', 'Ben', 'Constance', 'Dave', 'Emmet', 'Abel', 'Bice', 'Carol', 'Dennis']
n=3  
while i in range(len(a)-n+1):
  print('Window :', a[i:i+n])
  
  # Notice how I check a[i+n] does not get out of bounds.
  if i+n+1 < len(a) and a[i+n] == 'Abel':
      print()
      i += 3
      continue 
  i += 1
```

Comment: Now what will happen when the last element of `a` is `'Abel'`?

Comment: The window will **try** to restart and pick the next 3 elements in your list. If `'Abel'` is last, then there are no more elements for the window to select. Therefore the loop will terminate. You can handle that scenario differently depending on what you want to achieve.